# For each day get the sum of all rows in a very large Pandas DataFrame which match in two specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, dask, large-data

I have a very large Pandas DataFrame with 28171643 rows and 4 columns. A subset of this DataFrame for one day is shown below.

My task is now to calculate the total amount for `pair` for each day. The days range from 90 to 320. Please note that (as the name says) the `reversed` column always contains the flipped tuple from column `pair` in each row.

Here an example:

Row 0, 1, 2 and 4 all contain the same tuple combination, wether it is in column `pair` or `reversed` and therefore need to be sum up to 5+17+1604+1558 = 3184. Ideally this information is than stored in a new DataFrame with columns `day`, `amount` and `tuple`. It does not matter if `tuple` contains the value from `pair` or `reversed` as the combination is not directed.

I have a solution show below, but this takes way too long for this huge dataset!
As hardware I have a workstation with 48 cores 186GB RAM and a Quadro RTX 8000 GPU. If there is an easy solution with *Dask* for example or *rapids.ai* this is totally fine!

**My slow approach on a day-basis:**

If there is a way to parallelize this, it would also help!

```py
def analysis(d, t):

    combinations_df = d.loc[d['day'] == t]

    index = []

    for idx, row in combinations_df.iterrows():
        
        idd = combinations_df[combinations_df['reversed'] == row['pair']].index
        
        if len(idd) != 0:
            index.append(idd[0])
        else:
            index.append(-1)

    combinations_df['reversed_idx'] = index

    skippy = []
    to_drop = []
    
    def add_occurences(row):
        if row['reversed_idx'] == -1 or row['reversed_idx'] in skippy:
            return row
        else:
            row['amount'] += combinations_df.loc[row['reversed_idx']]['amount']
            skippy.append(row.name)
            to_drop.append(row['reversed_idx'])
            return row

    res = combinations_df.apply(lambda x: add_occurences(x), axis=1)
    skippy = set(skippy)
    to_drop = list(set(to_drop))
    return res.drop(to_drop)[['day', 'amount', 'pair']]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly as previous response with using groupby and agg but make the sum on unique key combination:

```
result = my_df.groupby(['day', my_df.pair.apply(set).apply(tuple)])[['amount']].agg('sum').reset_index()
```

With a random 5000 length DataFrame, making a loop on days with your function take for me 4.38 s ± 204 ms and now, I'm at 9.86 ms ± 185 µs

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

please consider adding some sample as code and not as `img` as it will make working with your code easier.

What you can do is `groupby` pair and then agg the summary of `amount`.

if the above table is `df` you can do:

```
>>> df = {'day': [226, 226, 226, 226, 226],
 'amount': [5, 17, 1604, 127, 1558],
 'pair': ['(B2141043,B2161043)',
  '(B2141043,B2161043)',
  '(B2141043,B2161043)',
  '(B2141043,C22D1043)',
  '(B2141043,B2161043)'],
 'reversed': ['(B2161043,B2141043)',
  '(B2161043,B2141043)',
  '(B2161043,B2141043)',
  '(C22D1043,B2141043)',
  '(B2161043,B2141043)']}

>>> df.groupby('pair').agg({'day' : 'first','amount': 'sum'})

                     day  amount
pair
(B2141043,B2161043)  226    3184
(B2141043,C22D1043)  226     127
```

Comment: Many thanks for you help but with your solution I still have both tuple orders in my DataFrame. @Boul`s solution overcomes this.